# How to disable a webpacker loader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

Webpacker requires the following loaders:

```
babel-loader
css-loader
file-loader
postcss-loader
sass-loader
style-loader
```

I want to experiment with skipping some or all of them. It it possible to do? The "thin" wrapper that webpacker provides around webpack is a bit thick for my brain. I struggle to change its config or even know what its total config is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the loaders can be modified through the loaders array like this:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
environment.loaders.delete('babel')
module.exports = environment
```

You can also insert new loaders or modify options on the existing ones.

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#loaders

Comment: If you test it and confirm that it works then I'll mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

The bit of code `environment.toWebpackConfig()` will return a big webpack config object. Part of that structure looks like

```
{"loaders": [
  {"key": "babel", "value": {...}},
  ...
]}
```

So you could do something like

```
var webpack_config = environment.toWebpackConfig();
webpack_config.loaders = webpack_config.loaders.filter(function(loader) {
  return loader.key !== "babel";
});
module.exports = webpack_config;
```

to selective filter out the loaders you don't want.